# How to add column numbers to each column in a large text file

Tags: python, awk, numbers, multiple-columns

I would like to add column numbers to 128 columns in a text file 
E.g.

My file

```
 12 13 14 15
 20 21 23 14
 34 56 67 89
```

Required output

```
  1:12     2:13    3:14     4:15
  1: 20    2:21    3: 23    4:14
  1: 34    2:56    3:67     4:89
```

Can this be done using awk / python 
I tried paste command for joining two files : one with the values other file with column numbers, manually typed. Since the file size is very large manual typing didnt work.
As of my knowledge I could find answers for adding only one column to the end of a text file.
Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Yes, it can easily be done with many different tools/programming languages. Please show what you tried first!

Comment: Thank you @karakfa I have tried paste command to join files(one with values one with column numbers manually generated) but since my file size is large I was unable to generate it manually.

Comment: Thanks @chrisz for editing the question

Comment: can anyone tell me why my question was down voted I am new to this site no idea about the reasons behind down votes

Comment: I didn't down vote, but read the first comment.  Question is fine but effort is missing.  Please update your post with the commands you tried but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa I have made the changes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i":"$i}1' file
```

should do.